# Checking a trigger function

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger addbook
  before insert
  on book
  for each row
DECLARE
 xcost float;
begin
 select avg(cost) into xcost
 from book;

  if :new.cost > xcost then
  INSERT INTO book (
    book_no,
    title,
    cost
) VALUES (:new.book_no,
:new.title,
  :new.cost
);
  end if;
end addbook;
/
```

//  .............. This is my trigger .It executed correctly but when I  do the following:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO book (
  2      book_no,
  3      title,
  4      cost
  5  ) VALUES (104,
  6  'C++ Brain work',
  7      500
  8  );
```

//  ............I got error like this :

```
INSERT INTO book (
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "EXP8.ADDBOOK", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EXP8.ADDBOOK'
ORA-06512: at "EXP8.ADDBOOK", line 8
```

//  What I will do???????

Comment: What are you expecting from your trigger? Your trigger is going into the infinite loop. `Insert into Book` in your trigger will again call that trigger and it will again call itself in an infinite loop. Please share your expected outcome.

Comment: In general a trigger should never use SQL to modify the same table which fires the trigger. You will wind up with an infinite loop or a "mutating table" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is triggering itself which causes a infinite loop and triggers the fail-safe protection showed. Either change your schema in order to record that changes in a second table or refactor your trigger to avoid entering in the infinite loop (additional column that according to its value would skip the second insertion)

I would prefer the first approach as it is much cleaner but I am speculating on your model.